# How to fix Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 12620 of 12651 bytes error?

Tags: errors

I get this PHP error notice in [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/). I tried disabling all plugins and applying a default theme like TwentyThenty, but the error doesn't go away. I also replaced wp-admin and wp-includes with new files, still no luck.
[image: unserialize() error]

Comment: have you recently disabled a plugin/switched theme or migrated a site to a new URL? Serialisation errors usually happen because the text was changed in the database and its length changed, making the length values incorrect

Comment: We change things all the time since it is an ongoing development. Is there any way to pinpoint the text that has changed?

Comment: but _how_ did you change it? Some ways will break your site if used, e.g. if you do a raw SQL search replace it will corrupt all serialised PHP containing those values if the length changes, with the only way to fix it being to do another seach replace that undoes the change, followed by a proper migration

Comment: the stack trace implies it's something privacy related, since it's a dev site you could delete it in an SQL client but that's no guarantee there aren't more options or values that are broken that will pop up afterwards. It looks like you've done something with a high chance of being highly destructive and this time when you rolled the dice you were unlucky